# JavaScript form submission doesn't send value of input type=submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post, forms

I'm using jQuery to, in some cases, automatically submit a form. Here's my code:

```
$("form [data-autosubmit]").closest("form").submit();
```

It works, however it doesn't send the name and value of the `input type=submit` button.

To elaborate, the following code:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="input" value="text they entered">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

would send the following POSTdata when submitted by the user:

```
input: text they entered
submit: Submit
```

However when the form is submitted by JavaScript, only this POSTdata is sent:

```
input: text they entered
```

My PHP scripts rely on the presence of a "submit" value in the POSTdata.

I was thinking I could do:

```
$("form [data-autosubmit]").closest("form").find("input[type=submit]").click();
```

But it seems to defy logic, when there is a `submit` event on the form intended for this purpose.

Comment: that sounds odd...you're right it should be showing up. i wonder if it's a browser issue. As a quick fix, I would simply just add an <input type="hidden" name="nameitwhatyouwant" value="already_submitted" /> in the form and then look for that instead.

Comment: @rnirnber That's what I used to do, but it's so untidy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML `form`s were built to support multiple `submit` inputs (so the same form could have an "Insert" and "Edit" button, for instance). Therefore the form relies on the click to actually register the chosen field in the `_POST` submission. Basically, HTML allows a form that looks like this:

```
<form [...]>
  <input type="submit" name="Insert" value="Insert">
  <input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update">
</form>
```

to be handled like this on the server-side:

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['Update'])){
  //Run update logic here..
}
elseif(!empty($_REQUEST['Insert'])){
  //Run insert logic here...
}
```

If the Javascript `submit()` function registered both buttons in the `POST` array it would break applications using this valid markup/logic, so they default to omitting `submit` inputs.

So your Javascript workaround (triggering a click on the submit button rather than just `submit()`ing the form) is the correct approach.

Comment: OK I guess I'll have to use the `click()` method then. Thanks for your explanation.